# hotmail smtp email issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, hotmail

I am using codeigniter for code.
Need to send email with hotmail and below are smtp credetial used:

```
                    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.live.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 587,
                    'smtp_user' => URL_EMAILID, // change it to yours
                    'smtp_pass' => URL_PASSWORD, // change it to yours
                    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                    'newline' => "\r\n",
                    'crlf' => "\r\n",
```

it send email in beginning ,but now it's give me error as below,

```
220 BLU437-SMTP71.smtp.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 8.0.9200.16384 ready at Mon, 28 Nov 2016 03:47:44 -0800
```

can any body help me to solve this error, I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: My advice... leave hotmail.

Comment: have you getting any error please put here..@hetal gohel